# Remote Firebird 3 client cannot connect to the DB on my PC

Tags: firebird

For years I was unable to get my app, on a laptop on my LAN, to connect to the db on my PC.
I was getting the “rejected by” message.
One day I was trying again and viola! It was connected. I do not remember what I had done on my PC (Win 10 Pro, FB 3). Then my PC C drive crashed. After reinstalling all the parts needed I am back to the rejected message. The PC firewall (Win Defender) has a Firebird entry using port 3050. The connection string is “ServerName:c:\FBData\dbname.fdb”.

I am stumped, again. Does anyone have tips on what do to connect?

Comment: Please provide more details, like what you are using to connect (programming language, tool, Firebird client version), the exact error message and details from the firebird.log from the Firebird server.

Comment: Using Delphi 10.3.2,  EMSSqlManager Firebird,  FB 3.0.4.33054, [FireDAC][Phys][FB]connection rejected by remote interface., Mon Dec 09 08:35:46 2019
 INET/inet_error: read errno = 10054, client host = ssd, address = fe80::ddd:70e8:f43e:b1fd%8/50501, user = great

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add extra information in the comments. And provide more context.

Comment: Address suggests use of IPv6. For a while i would disable IPv6 on both client and server and see if "good old" IPv4 would work. Or maybe i would run `cmd /k ping -4 servername` on the client to learn digital IPv4 address of the server (if it exists and is known) and then try to use that address instead of name in the Firebird connection string (with the similar goal of trying to force FB client out of IPv6)